# Regenerative braking using a normal RC ESC?

Tags: power, motor, motor-controller

I am thinking about building my own electric bike using RC parts.

I will be using a 2.2/2.4 kW motor and I will be using a ESC that is compatible with the motor.

My question is, during coasting or when I'm pedalling without powering the motor, is it possible to make the ESC convert the motors kinetic energy to electric energy to create an induced current to charge the battery?

Also, Is it possible to safely charge my LiPo battery with this voltage or should I use another type of battery?

Comment: If your coasting... do u really want to brake?

Comment: In addition to being off topic here, using an off-the-shelf RC ESC probably doesn't make sense on a bicycle anymore, especially if your awareness is at the level of needing to ask how.  Controllers intended for e-bikes are widely available.  Mistakes made with battery packs of these sizes are unforgiving.  Regenerative braking is a form of charging, and must be limited to what the pack can take, which when it is full, is nothing.

Comment: Good point, @Trevor, and he probably doesn't want regen when he's trying to pedal, either!

Comment: Unless your ESC is a combination ESC/battery charger, then no, it can't support it.

Comment: I think I've worded the title wrong... what I mean is, is there a way to charge the battery from the induced current that's produced from the bike coasting resulting in the motors spinning?